# Dropping primary key constraint and adding new primary key with auto increment populate data with EF code first

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have following table with composite key:
[image]

Now I want to remove composite key constraint, add new column with auto-increment option and add primary key constraint to that new column.

I do that with SQL statement:

```
BEGIN TRAN
ALTER TABLE dbo.ClaimFeeType
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ClaimFeeType;
ALTER TABLE dbo.ClaimFeeType ADD ClaimFeeTypeId int identity(1,1) not null
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.ClaimFeeType
add CONSTRAINT PK_ClaimFeeTypeId primary key(ClaimFeeTypeId)
GO
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

But how do I do that with Entity Framework Code First migrations?
To clarify I already have data, so I cannot afford to lose data, all I want to do is to remove composite keys, add new 1 column primary key with auto increment and automatically populate those Ids, which I already achieved with SQL statement above, but need to do this with migrations as I use entity framework.

Comment: Is (RoleID, Allocation) no longer a key?  Just because you add an _extra_ key doesn't mean you get to drop the natural key.  You can always add a the extra key with a unique index instead of changing the primary key.

Comment: i am dropping that composite key not needed yeah.